# Watin support for IE 9 - Part 1 (General)

Tags: watin, internet-explorer-9

I can't find any article about Watin and IE 9's compatibility. However, I have heard a few people say that Watin is not compatible with IE9. Now that IE 9 has been officially released, has anyone tried coupling the two? Does it work, any presets required? Eager to hear from you.

Cheers,
K

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to do basic things such as opening up the browser, navigating to page, filling in fields and clicking buttons. I am having a bit of a problem getting the browser to close after with the .close function, but that may be on my end.

Comment: For some reason, I can't get my Automation to work with IE 9 anymore. Could you please read my second post Watin support for IE 9 - Part 2 (Specific) and help me out? Thanks

Comment: Got the latest release of Watin (2.1 I think) and it now works with IE9. I still have issues with accessing the selected item of a dropdown list (raised as a new query). But this query is now resolved